# MongoDB -- TTL / Expire on Individual Fields?

Tags: database, mongodb

I have some database of ~2 billion documents and ~8 TB which I store for 90 days before dropping the documents. However, several of these fields contain much more data than the rest, and I only need them for a shorter time, say 30 days. After 30 days, I want to clear the fields out to free up space, before archiving the document entirely later on.

It doesn't seem that MongoDB has native functionality for TTL on individual fields.

The database is both write and read heavy.

I'm thinking about writing some script to query Mongo every 1 minute, and then do some query like:

`timestamp: $gt -30 days 1 hour AND $lt -30 days` and then `updateMany` to write `""` to these fields.

So essentially run a script every minute with a rolling window of one hour (just to ensure no documents escape) and doing an `updateMany`.

Is this a decent approach? Are there any design considerations I should be aware of when addressing this problem?

Comment: Would it make sense to store the fields with different retention requirements in a different collection, so they can be expired by the built-in methods?

Comment: I was considering this, but the index on `_id` alone is nearly 100GB, so we'd have to duplicate that and do some `join` logic etc. -- not sure if the TTL savings are worth the space/complexity costs